# Have you ever seen this product?

Tags: nt.number-theory

Given $k$, what is the value of the following product?
$$\prod_{p\textrm{ prime}}\left(1-\frac{k}{p^2}\right).$$
Clearly for $k=1$, we have $\zeta(2)^{-1}$ (where $\zeta(s)$ is the Riemann Zeta function).

Comment: Shouldn't zeta be $\zeta$ instead of xi?

Comment: @Suvrit: yes it should, I just edited it.$$ $$Besides $k=1$, we get $1$ for $k=0$, and zero if $k=p^2$ for some prime $p$.  Besides those trivial values, the product can be evaluated in closed form for $k=-1$ when it's $\zeta(2)/\zeta(4) = 15/\pi^2$, and probably for no other $k$, though it can be quickly evaluated, in the sense that it takes time polynomial in $n$ to approximate the product to within $\exp(-n)$.

Comment: For $k=0,1,2,3,4$ the product gives the proportion of integers $x$ such that $x+i$ is squarefree for $0 \leq i < k$.  The probability is $1$ for $k=0$ (trivially), $1/\zeta(2)=6/\pi^2$ for $k=1$ (as noted by Lapo), and $0$ for $k=4$ (the $p=2$ factor vanishes; one of $x,x+1,x+2,x+3$ is a multiple of $4$, so not squarefree).  For $k=2$ and $k=3$ the product can be evaluated numerically but is not expected to have a closed-form answer.

Answer (score 5):

Elementary comment. For a fixed real number $x$, define a multiplicative function $f(x;n)$ as follows. Factor $n=p_1^{e_1}\cdots p_r^{e_r}$ and set $f(x;n)=x^{e_1+\cdots+e_r}$. Then
$$
  \prod \left(1-\frac{x}{p^s}\right)^{-1} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{f(x;n)}{n^s}.
$$
The function $n\to e_1+\cdots+e_r$ that counts the number of prime divisors of $n$ with multiplicity must come up in lots of places, but I don't recall seeing it appear like this in a Dirichlet series.

Comment: That function is traditionally called $\Omega(n)$. The corresponding Dirichlet series can be found, for example, in Montgomery and Vaughan's "Multiplicative Number Theory" and probably in Tenenbaum's book as well.

Comment: @Greg: Thanks. You're probably talking about the Dirichlet series for $\Omega(n)$? The OP seems to want the Dirichlet series for $x^{\Omega(n)}$, at least for $x$ a positive integer and $s=2$.

Answer (score 3):

One standard calculation would be via

$$ \left(\frac{\zeta(2)}{\zeta(4)}\right)^k \left(\frac{\zeta(4)}{\zeta(8)}\right)^{\frac{k^2+k}{2}} \prod \left( 1- \frac{k}{p^2} \right) = \prod \left( 1- \frac{k}{p^2} \right) \left( 1 + \frac{1}{p^2} \right)^k \left( 1 + \frac{1}{p^4} \right)^{\frac{k^2+k}{2}} = \prod \left( 1 \pm O\left( \frac{1}{p^6} \right) \right).$$

You could iterate this method until you have an acceptable error term. I know, this is not the answer you asked for, but it would be an estimation.

Comment: Yes, that's the technique I meant when I commented that such products can be quickly calculated.